# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Different Login Page for Authorize Attribute

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have forms authentication wired up for my MVC 3 application. Normally when a request comes in that requires authentication, they are taken to my Login controller where they have to login.

However, I want a different view for this specific workflow because I plan on utilizing white labeling for my clients. Instead, I want them to go to a different endpoint in my Login controller to display my custom login view.

What options do I have to make this work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you elaborate on what you mean by white-label? What content will be changed and what will it depend on?

In your `Web.config` file look for

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="/Login/Index" />
    </authentication>
```

Change the `loginUrl` attribute to what you want it to be. Then, on the login action, select the proper view to return.

You'll need some type of identifier to distinguish clients (subdomain, cookie or something). Use that to select the proper view to return.

Comment: This seems by far the easiest approach.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you are doing but assuming that a user tries to go to this page:

```
http://example.com/Customer1/Index
```

and you want to redirect to

```
http://example.com/Customer1/Login
```

Assume that your normal login page is here:

```
http://example.com/Account/Login
```

You'll get a query string parameter **ReturnUrl**. So the request will go to your login page like this:

```
http://example.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=/Customer1/Index
```

So you can examine this parameter to determine where to redirect.